# Can't get request body with resify using Postman to send data

Tags: node.js, postman, restify

I am using a Restify server (node version is v9.11.1,  restify version is 6.4.0).

Here is my server config :

```
server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser({  mapParams: true }))
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser({  mapParams: true }));
server.pre(restify.plugins.pre.userAgentConnection());
server.use(restify.plugins.acceptParser(server.acceptable));

server.pre(cors.preflight);
server.use(cors.actual);
```

Now, I want to test with a code sample, using Postman. I want to test query params and body params :

```
server.post('/ping/:param1', (req, res, next ) => {
console.log(req.params);
console.log(req.body);
res.send(200, { "ping" :true} );
return next() ;
});
```

My Postman configurations:

- **Content-Type** as *application/json*
- POST on url : *http://127.0.0.1:8080/ping/value1* ( in order to test query parameters)
- Body as "Raw" with content : *{ "hello" : "world" }* ( to test body data)

After a POST query, I can get the query parameters, but I cant get the body data :

```
{ param1: 'value1' }
undefined
```

Comment: Try setting map params to false for the bodyParser.

Comment: It does not change anything when I set mapParams : false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a simple restify server with the server settings you listed above, with the exception of leaving out the cors stuff. I then hit the server using curl:

```
curl -F "hello=world" localhost:5555/ping/goodbye
```

and I got this on the server stdout:

```
{ param1: 'goodbye', hello: 'world' }
{ hello: 'world' }
```

I don't use Postman so I can't tell if it might not be working correctly for you, but this worked fine with curl.

My version info is as follows.

> process.versions
>       { http_parser: '2.7.0',
>         node: '8.2.1',
>         v8: '5.8.283.41',
>         uv: '1.13.1',
>         zlib: '1.2.11',
>         ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
>         modules: '57',
>         openssl: '1.0.2l',
>         icu: '59.1',
>         unicode: '9.0',
>         cldr: '31.0.1',
>         tz: '2017b' }

Comment: Thanks. I just have updated my Postman to last version, and it works fine now.